# Script to set mailbox size for a set of specific users

Tags: exchange-server-2013

I am using Exchange 2013 with different mailbox for different companies.
I want to set the mailbox size quota of all users having 100MB size to 200MB for example. Or to set the mailbox size of a specific mailbox to 500Mb.

Can someone help me to get a script for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is already not actual for topic starter but i leave it here:

```
get-user | ? {$_.company -eq "mycompany"} | set-mailbox -usedatabasequotadefaults:$false -ProhibitSendQuota 200Mb
```